Why does floating point value NaN cause collision detection to always return true?
There are few games I know that have a glitch where the player character's coordinates become NaN. The effect of this glitch is often described as the player "touching everything at once". This would meant that all of the collision detections done on the player object would return true. But why does this happen? From programming point of view, I don't see any sensible reason for that to happen, so it must be something in the floating point implementation/hardware that causes this.

give us an example of how collision detection algorithm works in brief. Is there any particular implementation you are talking about?

I don't have the source code for the games that have this bug, so I can't exactly do that...

If x is Nan then any operation involving x gives Nan, any comparison involving x is false. Just follow exactly the collision detection code and it will be obvious.
I would first check how come you have NaNs in your geometry data. That seems a bug to me, so fix that instead of the symptom. To check whether x is NaN, the easiest is to test "if (x != x)" which will be true for NaNs and not for anything else.
